Spell them out!
You find yourself waking up in a room, and it looks like you're stuck. You have no memory on how you got in there in the first place. You just remembered you were really drunk last night.
When looking around you find a piece of paper on the floor with some text and a large image under it.
The paper:

You're here because of consequences of what happened yesterday. See that number pad on the wall next to the locked door.. well, your task is to unlock the door by pressing the correct 4-digit code. I'm gonna give you only one chance to escape the room. If you solve it within today, i'll let you go. If you don't enter a code at all, you'll be stuck here for a year, but if you press an incorrect code you'll be stuck here forever. I've already been kind to you (if you get the hint) but I'm going to be kind again.. so - spell them out!. Next time..., think about the consequences before you do something you shouldn't be doing.


All you're thinking is - "What!? I have no idea what happened yesterday. Guess it's time to get to work..."
What 4-digit code do you enter in order for you to leave today? (You obviously don't want to be stuck there for a year either.)
Hint 1

 a) Focus on columns (spell them out!).  b) All rows must be valid times.


I enter:

 0000.

Spell them out!

 The hint tells us to spell out the columns. The grid on the right has six columns, but conceptually, there are only three columns. (That's why some of the numbers are written on the lines between cells.)

 Spell out what? The sketch on the left shows what looks like times where the hours, minutes and seconds have been replaced by question marks except in the lower left corner, where there are zeros. As in the grid to the right, there are six rows and we cann fill them in by spelling out each category:

         HH  7 :  MM  1 :  SS   
         OO    :  II 25 :  EE   
         UU    :  NN    :  CC  6 (+4)
         RR    :  UU    :  OO   
               :  TT  8 :  NN  4
               :  EE    :  DD  3

 (The two blanks after "hour" is where the zeros are.)

The numbers:

 The numbers in the grid range from 1 to 8 and each number occurs once. (25 must be read as two separate nubers, 2 and 5.) These numbers are indices of letters for an eight-letter word. There's one special instruction: The 6th letter is C and the +4 indicates that we must take the letter four letters after that, which is G.

 The letters spell MIDNIGHT, and on a 24-hour clock, midnight is represented as 0000. I assume that is the 4-digit code, which I nervously type into the number pad ...


Congrats, you're free :) My hint "b)" was just a way for me to let you know it's about valid times (if you convert the letters to numbers, you get (row for row) 08 13 19... 15 09 05 etc... to confirm that they're in 24-hour format and that the answer you've given must be the correct one. Well done!

Phew! Apart from the puzzle, the room didn't look too comfortable for a longer stay. I missed the second hint completely, probably because I'm from 24-hour land.
